# Adding button to header of Gutenberg editor in Wordpress through plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am developing a plugin for wordpress and I want to add the button to the header of gutenberg editor just like the one added by Elementor plugin "Edit with Elementor"

[image]

Can anyone guide me what should i do to achieve this... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

I've checked Guternberg source code on header toolbar and unfortunately right now there's only not a beautiful solution possible. You can have 'custom' buttons but they are only done through calling `registerPlugin` with `PluginSidebar` component which creates sidebar and button appears on right side for pinned\starred sidebars (like Yoast SEO does).

Elementor does it this way: it subscribes to `wp.data` store changes and whenever something happens it injects it's button if it's not yet injected. Just because React rerenders DOM it may eventually wipe button out, so subscribing to changes is important so if it wipes out custom button js code just reinjects it.

Below is simplified ES5 code to inject a custom link\button or really any custom HTML into it (just as Elementor does).

```
// custom-link-in-toolbar.js
// wrapped into IIFE - to leave global space clean.
( function( window, wp ){

    // just to keep it cleaner - we refer to our link by id for speed of lookup on DOM.
    var link_id = 'Your_Super_Custom_Link';

    // prepare our custom link's html.
    var link_html = '<a id="' + link_id + '" class="components-button" href="#" >Custom Link</a>';

    // check if gutenberg's editor root element is present.
    var editorEl = document.getElementById( 'editor' );
    if( !editorEl ){ // do nothing if there's no gutenberg root element on page.
        return;
    }

    var unsubscribe = wp.data.subscribe( function () {
        setTimeout( function () {
            if ( !document.getElementById( link_id ) ) {
                var toolbalEl = editorEl.querySelector( '.edit-post-header__toolbar' );
                if( toolbalEl instanceof HTMLElement ){
                    toolbalEl.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', link_html );
                }
            }
        }, 1 )
    } );
    // unsubscribe is a function - it's not used right now 
    // but in case you'll need to stop this link from being reappeared at any point you can just call unsubscribe();

} )( window, wp )
```

So create a js file in your theme or plugin and then link it this way:

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'custom_link_injection_to_gutenberg_toolbar' );
 
function custom_link_injection_to_gutenberg_toolbar(){
   // Here you can also check several conditions,
   // for example if you want to add this link only on CPT  you can
   $screen= get_current_screen();
   // and then
   if ( 'cpt-name' === $screen->post_type ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-link-in-toolbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom-link-in-toolbar.js', array(), '1.0', true );   
   }
   
}
```

Again this solution isn't perfect because we just inject our custom HTML into DOM which is managed by Gutenberg(React) but at this point it seems like the only way to achieve it, may be in future we'll have something like filters or hooks which will allow us to inject our custom components being rendered in toolbar  but not yet.

Still **Elementor** does it this way. you can check it's code at
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/master/assets/dev/js/admin/gutenberg.js

Comment: Why this setTimeout of 1 ms?

Comment: @Lovor, it's simply because in elementor's example, it's set to 1ms (at line 21).
My understanding why they've done it this way is: if it would be set to 0( no timeout) button injection logic would be executed once all other previously triggered actions were executed, the problem is that with 0 you can't be sure if React rerendered already everything  or triggered some repaint again  with timeout 0 so it may overwrite your dom changes so setting timeout to 1 just solves this potential issue. Still if you'll find out that with 0 it works reliably, your feedback is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a slot for the Main dashboard button you can use that one

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import {
    __experimentalFullscreenModeClose as FullscreenModeClose,
    __experimentalMainDashboardButton as MainDashboardButton,
} from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { close,image } from '@wordpress/icons';
 
const MainDashboardButtonIconTest = () => (
    <MainDashboardButton>
        <FullscreenModeClose icon={ close } href="http://wordpress.org" />
      
          <Button variant="primary" icon={image}>
                My Button
          </Button>

    </MainDashboardButton>
);
 
registerPlugin( 'main-dashboard-button-icon-test', {
    render: MainDashboardButtonIconTest,
} );
```

ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/main-dashboard-button/