# how to add a button in wordpress gutenberg main toolbar?

Tags: wordpress, toolbar, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to add a button in gutenberg main toolbar like below:

[image: gutenberg toolbar]

I am able to add a button in the block editor, toolbar but not in the main toolbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding button to header of Gutenberg editor in Wordpress through plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105561/adding-button-to-header-of-gutenberg-editor-in-wordpress-through-plugin)

Comment: no, i want to add a button in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

At present, [`<SlotFills>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/) does not expose a slot for the main toolbar. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16988) for creating a `<SlotFill>` to enable adding buttons to the main toolbar since around 2019. In the meantime, other plugins (eg. [Elementor](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/fab0d46aac98a4b09a92b7a0a7bf4fcbe1942b46/modules/admin-bar/module.php#L107)) that have added buttons to the main toolbar have found ways around it which may give you some ideas.